# Upsert is not updating existing document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Mongo creates a new document if it doesn't already exist (must have the `id` of 1). And if it already exists, it should increment all values by 1. But the problem here is that it adds another document every time, instead of updating the already existing one.

```
const query = {
        id: 1,
        customer: {
            worth: 0
        }
    },
    update = { id: 1, $inc: 
        { 
            'customer.worth': 1
        } 
    },
    options = { upsert: true };

Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

How can I just increment the value of 1 if document already exists, instead of adding another document every time? I only want to have 1 document at any given time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query seems ok and inserts during update caused by **`upsert`** flag

> Optional. If set to true, creates a new document when no document
> matches the query criteria. The default value is false, which does not
> insert a new document when no match is found.

[read documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-parameter)

the following query worked for me

```
db.getCollection('test').findOneAndUpdate({
        "id" : 1,
        "customer" : {
            "worth" : 0
          }  
        }, {
          $inc: {
            'customer.worth': 1
          }
        })
```